# Foreach : Loop Images to Appear in Slider

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am using a foreach loop to show up images to appear in the slider. The resultset is as follows:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'file_name' => string 'SHG_Petty_shop2.jpg' (length=19)

  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'file_name' => string 'Manavanur_Statue_innaug3.jpg' (length=28)

  2 => 
    array (size=1)
        'file_name' => string 'SHG_Group_meeting6.jpg' (length=22)

  3 => 
    array (size=1)
       'file_name' => string 'Low_cost_toilet4.jpg' (length=20)
```

Below is the code i did to make the slider in view.

```
<?php foreach($slider_info as $key=>$slider) 
                        { ?> 

                         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item active">
                            <img style="height: 300px;width:100%;" src="<?php //echo base_url();?>upload/sliderimages/<?php echo $slider['file_name']; ?>" height="100" alt="Image of every carousel"/>

   </div>
                    </div>  
            <?php } ?>
```

But things are not working as i expected.. I want all the images from the result set to be shown up in the image  carousel. I am trying using the foreach loop in codeigniter. I got all the images in the slider, but it shown up horizontally, the slider is not working .Kindly help..

Comment: What is the HTML output of your attempt?

Comment: I think <div class="item active"> is not proper, this class should only be there to current slide, for every other slide this should be removed.

Comment: replace this <?php echo $slider['file_name']; ?> to <?php echo $slider; ?>

Comment: when you say things are not working as expected, what do you mean? No images displayed? Also properly format your code so we know where the last div ends or if you are missing a div

Comment: @JimWright, It showned all the images horizontally one by one, but the slider dint work..!

Comment: @Keynes : it means you don't have problem with image loading, all are loading but slider thing not working.

Comment: @kishor10d, yes the slider is not working, i shall modify the question

Comment: No if is a problem of slider you need to open a new question please I think @Keynes

Comment: its ok @AlessandroMinoccheri, i thought it can be achieved in php

Comment: Did you try to move 2 div outside your foreach loop? Because you set all images in active class

Comment: @AdhanTimothyYounes, I tried but it has not shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:
An "active" class must be appended on the first slide, not for all.

```
<?php
    $slider_info[] = array('file_name'=> 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg' );
    $slider_info[] = array('file_name'=> 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg' );
    $slider_info[] = array('file_name'=> 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg' );
    $slider_info[] = array('file_name'=> 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg' );
    $slider_info[] = array('file_name'=> 'https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/ny.jpg' );
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
         <?php foreach($slider_info as $key=>$slider) { ?> 

            <div class="item <?php echo ($key == 0) ? "active" : ""; ?> ">
                <img style="height: 300px;width:100%;" src="<?php  echo $slider['file_name']; ?>" height="100" alt="Image of every carousel"/>
           </div>

        <?php } ?>
        </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: use next-prev buttons of carousel for change slides.
https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_carousel&stacked=h

Comment: i clicked the next-prev buttons but it has not responded new images

Comment: The above code has shown up all the images horizontally one by one

Comment: @Keynes: plz run above code in a separate file in your project. it should work.

Comment: pls answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299406/foreach-get-a-particular-iteration-value

Answer (score 1):

try to change this:

```
<?php foreach($slider_info as $key=>$slider)
```

to this:

```
<?php foreach($slider_info as $slider)
```

Because you don't need the key value inside your loop, you need to take the array with its value

Comment: The problem of the slider could be a javascript problem, so it's another quetion. Before this step of loop, try to insert static image into the carousel and fix the javascript call of the plugim, this question is about php and loop

Comment: pls answer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299406/foreach-get-a-particular-iteration-value

Comment: If this question is close please close it and accept an answer to help other guys with your same problem @Keynes