# Foreach: Get a particular iteration value

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am having four images inside a code igniter `foreach` loop.For one of my project, I want to take image of the third iteration from the loop. Is it possible to take the particular iteration? I hope it is a weird question . But, I need to take separate iteration values, for my separate `<div>` in my view of MVC.

The following is the result, coming from controller.

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'file_name' => string 'PHP_Petty_shop12.jpg' (length=20)

  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'file_name' => string 'Manavanur_innagration123.jpg' (length=28)

  2 => 
    array (size=1)
        'file_name' => string 'SHG_Group_meeting6.jpg' (length=22)

  3 => 
    array (size=1)
       'file_name' => string 'Low_cost_toile17.jpg' (length=20)
```

The following is the code which i tried to get the iterated value..

```
<?php foreach($slider_info as $key=>$slider) 
                        { ?> 

                         <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="item <?php echo ($key == 4) ? "active":""; ?> ">
                            <img style="height: 300px;width:100%;" src="<?php echo base_url();?>upload/sliderimages/<?php echo $slider['file_name']; ?>" height="100" alt="Image of every carousel"/>

   </div>
                    </div>  
            <?php } ?>
```

I am not able to get the desired output. Is there a way?

Comment: Directly access `$slider_info[3]`…?!

Comment: yes one time 3rd iteration after that exit

Comment: if its not possible, i will have to delete this question yaar

Comment: Well, again: instead of doing a `foreach` and "accessing the 3rd iteration"… Just directly access `$slider_info[3]`…!? `$slider = $slider_info[3];`

Comment: @deceze, Is that possible yaar

Comment: @deceze, it shown me an error message as `Array to String Conversion` Error

Comment: Why don't you check for `$key==2` ?

Comment: @Rahul, yes doing that provides the third image

Comment: So your issue is resolved then.

Comment: yes indeed yaar, just post in your answer, in such a way that the key is different in the loop `foreach($slider_info as $key=>$slider)`

Comment: @Keynes: Can you explain in detail, what you need exactly?

Comment: @AshokGujjar, i want to take a 3rd iteration from the for each loop

Comment: But what is your purpose?

Comment: @AshokGujjar, in the bottom of the gallery page, want to show a image which comes in the 3rd iteration..

Comment: @Keynes: Try <img src="<?php echo $slider_info[2]['file_name']; ?>" > , And see what happpens.